# Scrapy redirects me even when handling 302 status

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm facing some issue through amazon scraping. I keep being redirected (302) on pages that doesnt provide any result, while I use (I believe) appropriate settings.

Here is start_requests function : I build a search URL based on product codes that come from a CSV file :

```
def start_requests(self):
    input_file_products = open("file.csv", 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
    reader = csv.reader(input_file_products)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            base_url = "https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?"
            "__mk_fr_FR=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="
            ean = row[0]
            absolute_url = base_url + ean
            yield scrapy.Request(
                absolute_url,
                meta={
                    'dont_redirect': True,
                    "handle_httpstatus_list": [302, 301],
                },
                callback=self.parse
            )
```

However I get codes like this :
DEBUG: Scraped from <302 https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?3538280031515>

And don't get any results. I already specified don't redirect as True, and handled codes 302 and 301 as advised.

How would you do ?

Answer (score 1):

when i search in through search bar, my link was : [search link](https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Dautomotive&field-keywords=laptop)

but it doesn't match yours, from `search-alias%3D` to onward.it might generate the link dynamic, update your link and try again.

Comment: I updated with yours and it wasn't working...however I updated again after a new search through search bar as well and this time it works ! It seems not to be the same link for everyone so I hope other people using the script dont get redirected